# What does it mean " Kubernetes needs to be have the Extension API Server feature enabled"?

Tags: kubernetes

I am reading the README file for [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus#prerequisites) and is confused by the following passage:

> This stack provides resource metrics by deploying the Prometheus
> Adapter. This adapter is an Extension API Server and Kubernetes needs
> to be have this feature enabled, otherwise the adapter has no effect,
> but is still deployed.

What does it mean to have the Extension API Server feature enabled? I have consulted the page on [feature gates in K8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) and on [setting up an Extension API Server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/setup-extension-api-server/#setup-an-extension-api-server-to-work-with-the-aggregation-layer) but neither seem to indicate an existence of a dedicated feature to enable for Extension API Servers.

What am I missing?

P.S.

I use an Azure managed K8s cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation you need is under enabling aggregation.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-aggregation-layer/#enable-kubernetes-apiserver-flags

The section you are looking for is https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-aggregation-layer/#enable-kubernetes-apiserver-flags

It looks like the flags needed are

```
--requestheader-client-ca-file=<path to aggregator CA cert>
--requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
--requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
--requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
--requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
--proxy-client-cert-file=<path to aggregator proxy cert>
--proxy-client-key-file=<path to aggregator proxy key>
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to check it on an Azure managed K8s cluster? Maybe this can be fetched as a YAML configuration somehow?

Comment: I haven't really run many managed clusters on Azure. But I'd start looking at the az aks command documentation -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest

The aks show command would be a good bet, I haven't had a chance to use it yet though